# How to get total length of JSON object using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have JSON in URL and I am showing the total length of JSON array, but not showing the length of an object. Please view the code and correct the code.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/hehe/GetAllBus",
            data: "",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (dataBus1) {
                loaddataBus(dataBus1);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Failed! Please try again.");
            }
        });
    });

    function myFunction() {
        var fruits = dataBus1;
        document.getElementById("demo12").innerHTML = fruits.length;
    }
```

Print the length of array

```
<code>
   <body onload="myFunction()">
       <p id="demo12"</p>
    </body>
</code>
```

Comment: what is loaddataBus? it should be a function which assign globe variable dataBus1.

Comment: Close your `<p>` tag in your HTML code, that would be a first thing

Comment: If `/hehe/GetAllBus` returns the `array of objects` then you can find the length using `dataBus1.length` . but if its an `object` then you have to  try `Object.keys(dataBus1).length`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/hehe/GetAllBus",
        data: "",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (dataBus1) {
            loaddataBus(dataBus1);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Failed! Please try again.");
        }
    });
});
function loaddataBus(fruits) {
    document.getElementById("demo12").innerHTML = fruits.length;
}
```

You don't even need the onload on body:

```
<body>
   <p id="demo12"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
success: function (dataBus1) {
            loaddataBus(dataBus1);
},

...

function myFunction() {
    var fruits = dataBus1;
    document.getElementById("demo12").innerHTML = fruits.length;
}
```

to:

```
success: function (dataBus1) {
            myFunction(dataBus1);
},

...

function myFunction(dataBus1) {
    var fruits = dataBus1;
    document.getElementById("demo12").innerHTML = fruits.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget to close the p  tag (missing symbol '>' after "demo12")

```
<code>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<p id="demo12"></p>

</body>
</code>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using jQuery, which it looks like, there is a easier and faster way:
Using [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/).

**JS (can be in `<head>` or in `<body>` :**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("/hehe/GetAllBus", function(data){
            $('#demo12').html(data.length);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <p id="demo12"></p>
</body>
```

For more feedback:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.getJSON("/hehe/GetAllBus", function(){
            console.log("fetched json");
        })
        .done(function(data){
            $('#demo12').html(data.length);
        });
        .fail(function(){
            console.log("error");
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In your code you have written ajax inside `ready` event which will fire after `onload` so data is not available.

```js
function myFunction() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://mysafeinfo.com/api/data?list=englishmonarchs&format=json",
    data: "",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(dataBus1) {
      var fruits = dataBus1;
      document.getElementById("demo12").innerHTML = dataBus1.length;
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("Failed! Please try again.");
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<code>
   <body onload="myFunction()">
       <p id="demo12"</p>
    </body>
</code>
```